# Codeigniter wont redirect in netbeans

Tags: apache, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have got this url:

```
http://localhost:85/WebCamClone/Home
```

But it will only load like this:

```
http://localhost:85/WebCamClone/index.php/Home
```

I tried to put htaccess rule like this one:

```
  RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But it didnt work. What else should I try?

This is what is inside my apache config file:

```
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in apaches config file.. I had to go to its file and replace allowoveride none to allow override all

Answer (score 1):

In `application/config/config.php` have you removed `index.php` from `$config['index_page']` so that it looks like:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: yeah..see update.. I think it is something to do with apache permission rights

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code once in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```